# На компютере выполняется запрос идеально а с смартфона нет речь идёт о запросе АJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, mobile-web

На компютере выполняется запрос идеально а с смартфона нет. Pечь идёт о запросе АJAX c последующим создовании елементов и добовление этих елементов в страницу.

Понемаю что я совсем зелённый в этом деле (программирование) и может базовых вещей не знаю но прошу помочь ( погуглил но не нашёл решение ).

Задача: Поиск товаров из БД;

Структура: при набирании текста в инпуте, JQUERY отслеживает изминение и делает запрос AJAX запрос к серверу через PHP и SQL получаем список подходящих товаров. JQUERY получает список и создаёт для каждого елемента новый блок DIV и загружает его в страницу.

ПРОБЛЕММА: На компютере работает а вот если с СМАРТФОНА набираю текст нет результата никакого.

Сылка на рабочий сайт: http://wo-market.com

SCRIPT:

```
$('#searchText').keypress(function (){
    if(event.keyCode==13){
        var findText = $('#searchText').val();
        if(findText.length>=3){
            location.href = '/product/show/'+findText+'/';
            $("#searchResult").remove();
        }
    }else{
    var findText = $('#searchText').val();
    if(findText.length>=3){
        $("#searchResult").remove();
        $("#searchBar a").attr('href','/product/show/'+findText+'/');
        findProductsByFindText(findText);
    };}
});
```

/**
 *Поиск товара
 *
 */

```
function findProductsByFindText(findText){
var findT = findText;
var findText = "findText=" + findT;

$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    async:true,
    url:"/product/find/",
    data: findText,
    dataType:'json',
    success: function(data){
        if(data){
            console.log(" 1 - " + findText + " :: " + data);
            resultProductsFromFindText(data);
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }

})
}
```

/**
 *Афиширование товара под Инпутом поиск
 *
 */

```
 function resultProductsFromFindText(res){

    var resData = res;
    var searchField = document.getElementById("searchBar");
    var searchResult = document.createElement('div');

    searchResult.setAttribute("id", "searchResult");
    searchField.appendChild(searchResult);


    for(i=0;i<resData.length;i++){

        searchResult.appendChild(addProduct(resData[i]));
    }
 }
```

/**
 *Создание елемента товара из поиска
 *
 */

```
function addProduct(i) {
     var i = i;
     var div = document.createElement('div');

     div.innerHTML = '<a href="/product/' + i['id'] + '/">' + i['name_ru'] + '</a><a href="/product/' + i['id'] + '/"><img src="/images/products/' + i['image']+ '" width=50 height=50 /><a><br />' ;

     div.setAttribute("class", "searchProduct");
     return div;

} ;
```

Comment: В андроиде нет события keypress. Надо использовать keydown или keyup.

Comment: так да, ошибка в файле http://wo-market.com/js/ready.js вот здесь: $('#searchText').keypress(function (){
        if(event.keyCode==13){.... Надо менять эту функцию на универсальную

Comment: Спасибо тебе огромное, сработало. Буду знать на будущее!

Answer (score 1):

1. Смартфоны могут капризничать, если структура страницы корявая, в частности, добавь `<!DOCTYPE html>`
2. Отключи вывод в консольку `console.log`, зачем это на боевом сайте????
3. в Мозилле также поиск не исправен. У тебя там ошибка в скриптах есть, но это к разработчикам, они же хлеб не зря едят....

Comment: Как у тебя i стало массивом в функции addProduct()?

Comment: шо?..............

Comment: Да, точно, пардон. i это ответ на ajax.